# How to use Flutter Semantics?

Tags: flutter, dart

According to the [video](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html)

To wrap a widget in Semantics you simply change

```
Text('Hello World')
```

into

```
Semantics(child: Text('Hello World'))
```

However, I receive `error: The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.`

How would I do this with a const constructor?

Dart SDK version: 2.14.0 (stable) (Mon Sep 6 13:47:59 2021 +0200) on "macos_x64"
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 12.0 21A5506j darwin-x64, locale en-US)

```
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      showSemanticsDebugger: true,
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          // child: Text('Hello World'),
          child: Semantics(child: Text('Hello World')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Trying to add const before the Text produces an additional error:

[image: additional error]

Comment: What version of flutter are you using? also share your complete source code

Comment: @I_am_programmer Added full source and versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Semantics()` constructor is not a `const` constructor. The parent widget `Center` is calling a `const` constructors, which requires all children to have a `const` constructor as well. Update your body to:

```dart
body: Center(
  child: Semantics(child: const Text('Hello World')),
),
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. I'm still receiving the error along with a new one ```The constructor being called isn't a const constructor. (Documentation)  Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.```

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: You didn't completely update your code to my recommended changes. You shouldn't use `const Center` in your body.

Comment: I removed const from Center and it works. The default code had const though...

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: That right. The default code was fine the way it was. The nested child widget `Semantics` doesn't have a `const` constructor. So you were receiving this error due to the parent widget `Container` using `const` when a child widget you added did not have a `const` constructor. Hope that helps.